# Как правильно сказать: "вопрос возникает" или "вопрос встает"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Как сказать правильно: вопрос **возникает** или вопрос **встает**?*

Comment: Почему я ставлю плюс этому вопросу? Возможно, здесь речь идет только о правильности употребления слов. Но меня он заставляет задуматься об образности нашего языка, о его метафоричности. Казалось бы, встал или возник - какая разница? Разницы нет, если у людей нет слуха, нет интереса к родному языку. "Встать" для вопроса  - это присутствовать изначально, а потом  подняться, чтобы тебя видели. А "возникнуть" - это вдруг  "предстать перед глазами, показаться неожиданно и внезапно, как из-под земли. Ты откуда возник (появился, взялся, разг.)?

Answer (score 3):

**Употребляются оба выражения, хотя с разной частотностью.** Из Нацкорпуса:  встает вопрос (327 примеров), возникает вопрос (1156 примеров).

Можно предположить, что глаголы всё-таки имеют разные **смысловые оттенки**, а именно: **встает** вполне ожидаемый и закономерный вопрос по теме дискуссии, а **возникает** вопрос неожиданный,  связанный со смежными проблемами (**но это просто одна из версий)**.

**Примеры:** И тут, **конечно**, встаёт вопрос: а зачем? **Ибо тогда** встаёт вопрос: сможет ли телевидение технически развиваться и сможет ли оно закупать хорошие фильмы. **Но тогда** встаёт вопрос: что это?

**Возникает вопрос**: а правильно ли это вообще ― тратить бюджетные деньги на промышленные стандарты, по которым работает частный бизнес? **Тут прежде всего возникает вопрос:** во что можно сегодня вложиться?

Answer (score 0):

"**Возникает вопрос**" - выражение имеет буквальный смысл, напр. в ситуации, когда понадобилось выяснить что-то непонятное. Это просто элемент рассуждения о чём-то.

> Возникает вопрос: почему он сразу не сказал об этом?

"**Встаёт вопрос**" - в типичном случае это о проблеме, с которой сталкиваются; предстоит что-то сделать. В этом есть и элемент вопроса (как быть: решать проблему или уклониться о её решения; если решать, то как, когда и т. п.), но здесь "вопрос" проистекает из *насущной потребности*, "встаёт и заявляет сам о себе".

> Встаёт вопрос о привлечении его к ответственности.

Comment: Возможно, есть связь: вопросы возникают там, где употребляют сочетание "задать  вопрос"; вопросы встают там,  где "ставят вопросы".